# Dragging an object by touching on Android

Tags: android, unity, ios, touch

I am trying to move and object by touching it and dragging. I am testing it on my Samsung Galaxy SIII.

I have used the following code. For some reason it moves faster than my finger. It should always be beneath my finger. What is wrong? (note: I haven't done the "only move object if you touch onto it" part, so right now it moves where ever I touch)

```
#pragma strict

var speed : float = 1;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && 
        Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {



        // Get movement of the finger since last frame
        var touchDeltaPosition:Vector2 = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

        var touchPosition:Vector2;

        touchPosition.Set(touchDeltaPosition.x, 
                           touchDeltaPosition.y );


        // Move object across XY plane
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position,
                                                touchPosition, 
                                                Time.deltaTime*speed);
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the time your finger takes to move from one point to another as the speed (v = d/t) instead of a normal speed value? Well, in my head it makes sense...

Comment: That's because, usually, worldspace and screenspace have different coordinates. Adding the delta won't work. You have to use the camera and Unproject the finger coordinates to worldspace.